# RANK() OVER PARTITION with RANK resetting

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

How can I get a RANK that restarts at partition change?
I have this table:

```
ID    Date        Value  
1     2015-01-01  1  
2     2015-01-02  1 <redundant  
3     2015-01-03  2  
4     2015-01-05  2 <redundant  
5     2015-01-06  1  
6     2015-01-08  1 <redundant  
7     2015-01-09  1 <redundant  
8     2015-01-10  2  
9     2015-01-11  3  
10    2015-01-12  3 <redundant
```

and I'm trying to delete all the rows where the Value is not changed from the previous entry (marked with **< redundant**).
I've tried using cursors but it takes too long, as the table has ~50 million rows.

I've also tried using RANK:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Value,
RANK() over(partition by Value order by Date ASC) Rank,
FROM DataLogging 
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

but I get:

```
ID    Date        Value  Rank   (Rank)
1     2015-01-01  1      1      (1)
2     2015-01-02  1      2      (2)
3     2015-01-03  2      1      (1)
4     2015-01-05  2      2      (2)
5     2015-01-06  1      3      (1)
6     2015-01-08  1      4      (2)
7     2015-01-09  1      5      (3)
8     2015-01-10  2      3      (1)
9     2015-01-11  3      1      (1)
10    2015-01-12  3      2      (2)
```

in parantheses is the Rank I would want, so that I can filter out rows with Rank = 1 and delete the rest of the rows.

EDIT: I've accepted the answer that seemed the easiest to write, but unfortunately none of the answers runs fast enough for deleting the rows.
In the end I've decided to use the **CURSOR** afterall. I've split the data in chuncks of about 250k rows and the cursor runs through and deletes the rows in ~11 mins per batch of 250k rows, and the answers below, with DELETE, take ~35 mins per batch of 250k rows.

Comment: In your example, how do you tell the first set of `value = 1` (`id`s 1 and 2) from the second set (`id`s 5, 6, and 7)?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. taken chronologicaly there are other values in between.

Comment: @AlinI: Does it matter to you which specific rows are considered redundant in each group?  E.g., does it matter if the *earliest* row is kept vs. the *latest* row in each group?

Comment: yes, it matters, the earliest row should remain in table.

Comment: Wouldn't any classic "gaps and islands" solution work for this?  Your end-goal isn't to get a Rank is it?   It's just to delete "redundant" rows?

Comment: The problem with your attempts based on the window function version of `RANK()` is that the partitions you want are not determined strictly by the `value` column, nor indeed by *any* combination of columns.  They are functions of pairs of rows, relative to a particular row order.  The `lag()` and `lead()` window functions are just the thing for handling this, as Gordon suggested in his answer.

Comment: What SQL Server version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
from  ( select ID, Date, Value, lag(Value, 1, 0) over (order by ID) as ValueLag 
        from table ) tt
where ValueLag is null or ValueLag <> Value
```

if the order is Date then over (order by Date)

this should show you good and bad  - it is based on ID - it you need date then revise
it may look like a long way around but it should be pretty efficient

```
declare @tt table  (id tinyint, val tinyint);
insert into @tt values 
( 1, 1),
( 2, 1),
( 3, 2),
( 4, 2),
( 5, 1),
( 6, 1),
( 7, 1),
( 8, 2),
( 9, 3),
(10, 3);

select id, val, LAG(val) over (order by id) as lagVal
from @tt;

-- find the good
select id, val 
from ( select id, val, LAG(val) over (order by id) as lagVal
       from @tt 
     ) tt
where  lagVal is null or lagVal <> val 

-- select the bad 
select tt.id, tt.val 
  from @tt tt
  left join ( select id, val 
                from ( select id, val, LAG(val) over (order by id) as lagVal
                         from @tt 
                     ) ttt
               where   ttt.lagVal is null or ttt.lagVal <> ttt.val 
            ) tttt 
    on tttt.id = tt.id 
 where tttt.id is null
```

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't familiar with the LEAD function.  Seems pretty useful.  I didn't downvote but it's not clear how to take this to the next step (removing the redundant rows).

Comment: Not my downvote, but it may be the first revision of your answer had a syntax error. Hopefully, they can take it back when they notice that you fixed it

Comment: You did show a select.   Lead / lag is very efficient when you only want adjacent.

Comment: Something is not quite right with the logic here,, it returns rows `2, 4, 7, 8, 10`.  If the intention is to reveal redundant rows, it should return `2, 4, **6**, 7, 10`.

Comment: @mellamokb My intention is that it would show the good rows.  I will look at it.

Comment: @Frisbee: Ah, it **is** working in a manner of speaking.  It does remove redundant rows, just not the specific redundant rows indicated by OP :).  Guess it comes down to whether OP cares whether the *first* row is kept in each value group, or the *last* row.

Comment: @mellamokb That should be keeping the first. Based on show the good rows.

Comment: I've tried this solution, and yes, it shows the good rows if I want the last entry, **but I want the first entry in each group.**

Comment: @Frisbee Accepted your answer, but read the EDIT in OP. Thanks

Comment: @AlinI You should try this with a delete top (100000)  in a loop

Answer (score 5):

Here is a somewhat convoluted way to do it:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) RN1,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY [Date]) RN2
    FROM dbo.YourTable
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Value, RN1 - RN2 ORDER BY [Date]) N
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE2
ORDER BY ID;
```

The results are:

```
╔════╦════════════╦═══════╦═════╦═════╦═══╗
║ ID ║    Date    ║ Value ║ RN1 ║ RN2 ║ N ║
╠════╬════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╬═══╣
║  1 ║ 2015-01-01 ║     1 ║   1 ║   1 ║ 1 ║
║  2 ║ 2015-01-02 ║     1 ║   2 ║   2 ║ 2 ║
║  3 ║ 2015-01-03 ║     2 ║   3 ║   1 ║ 1 ║
║  4 ║ 2015-01-05 ║     2 ║   4 ║   2 ║ 2 ║
║  5 ║ 2015-01-06 ║     1 ║   5 ║   3 ║ 1 ║
║  6 ║ 2015-01-08 ║     1 ║   6 ║   4 ║ 2 ║
║  7 ║ 2015-01-09 ║     1 ║   7 ║   5 ║ 3 ║
║  8 ║ 2015-01-10 ║     2 ║   8 ║   3 ║ 1 ║
║  9 ║ 2015-01-11 ║     3 ║   9 ║   1 ║ 1 ║
║ 10 ║ 2015-01-12 ║     3 ║  10 ║   2 ║ 2 ║
╚════╩════════════╩═══════╩═════╩═════╩═══╝
```

To delete the rows you don't want, you just need to do:

```
DELETE FROM CTE2
WHERE N > 1;
```

Comment: this seems to work, but if I use **SELECT ID FROM CTE2 WHERE N > 1 ORDER BY ID;** i get too many rows: ~237k vs ~175k which are redundant.

Comment: @AlinI I just replicated the expected result posted in your question

Comment: If I get the whole table it's true, the rankings are as expected. Now, how do I go about deleting the unnecesarry rows?

Comment: That can't be right. If I do **SELECT FROM CTE2 WHERE N > 1** I get 237k rows... how is the **DELETE** only delete 175k?

Comment: @AlinI Sorry, I don't get what you said

Comment: Sorry, you are right, the results were good indeed. just that the DELETE takes a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the rows, I would suggest you use `lag()`:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, lag(value) over (order by date) as prev_value
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where value = prev_value;
```

I'm not quite sure what `rank()` has to do with the problem.

EDIT:

To see the rows *not* deleted with the same logic:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, lag(value) over (order by date) as prev_value
      from t
     )
select *
from todelete
where value <> prev_value or prev_value is null;
```

The `where` clause is just the inverse of the `where` clause in the first query, taking `NULL` values into account.

Comment: this seems to work, but if I use **SELECT ID FROM todelete where value = prev_value;** i get too many rows: ~237k vs ~175k which are redundant

Comment: @AlinI . . . You want `where value <> prev_value or prev_value is null`.  Your logic returns the rows being deleted, rather than the ones being kept.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting so I'd thought I'd jump in. Unfortunately, creating a solution with `RANK()` (or rather, `ROW_NUMBER()`) without first transforming the data looks to be unobtainable. In an attempt to transform the data, I came up with this solution that uses 1 `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
;WITH Ordered AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS [Row], *
    FROM DataLogging
),
Final AS
(
    SELECT
        o1.*, NULLIF(o1.Value - ISNULL(o2.Value, o1.Value - 1), 0) [Change]
    FROM
        Ordered o1
        LEFT JOIN Ordered o2 ON
            o1.[Row] = o2.[Row] + 1
)
SELECT * FROM Final
```

In the last `Change` column, the value will be `NULL` if there is no change in value (but will have the difference if there is a change).

So to do the delete, change the select to

```
DELETE FROM DataLogging where Change IS NULL
```

**Edit:** Lag would work here too but I was visualizing the solution as I went along and completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for my case! thanks
I had to fetch the report_to change for an employee with respect to the previous reports_to valueand effdt. 
In other words, fetcth min effective date row for each reports_to change for an employee.

with tocheck as (
      select T.emplid,T.reports_to,T.effdt, lag(reports_to) over (order by effdt) as prev_value
      from PS_JOB t
     )
select *
from tocheck
where reports_to <> prev_value or prev_value is null;

added changes further as p