# SQL unable to partition with multiple columns in desired manner

Tags: sql, t-sql, partition

The below script and output demonstrates my issue and query.

What I am trying to do is find a way of selecting the first product assigned date within a particular "grouping" that may occur against a customer.

So here, in the output I am wanting rows 5 and 6 to have ranks of 1 and 2, and show the date of 2020-04-05.
In this scenario, SQL is seeing all product 3s as being in the same group.
I was wondering if there was a simple way around this - I know I can do this in a long winded manner using a cursor and temp table possibly, but that won't be efficient for our entire customer base - so can this be done cleanly?

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING(PRODUCT_ID INT, PRODUCT_ASSIGNED_DATE DATETIME)

INSERT TESTING VALUES(3, '2020-01-01')
INSERT TESTING VALUES(3, '2020-02-01')
INSERT TESTING VALUES(3, '2020-03-01')
INSERT TESTING VALUES(5, '2020-03-05')
INSERT TESTING VALUES(3, '2020-04-05')
INSERT TESTING VALUES(3, '2020-04-15')

SELECT 
    rank() over (partition by PRODUCT_ID ORDER BY PRODUCT_ASSIGNED_DATE) as rank1,
    FIRST_VALUE (PRODUCT_ASSIGNED_DATE) over (partition by PRODUCT_ID ORDER BY PRODUCT_ASSIGNED_DATE) as 'FirstAssignedInGroup'
FROM TESTING
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ASSIGNED_DATE
```

Output: -

```
1   2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
2   2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
3   2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
1   2020-03-05 00:00:00.000
4   2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
5   2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: What happened to the first 4 rows?

Comment: Hi Nozzle. I think you are missing a customer id in your sample table. Since you yourself mentioned "particulary "grouping" that may occur against a customer." Once you introduce the customer id to your partition statement it should work as you expect.

Comment: does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208241/rank-over-partition-with-rank-resetting